# Variable Path for Output?

Tags: java

How can I set a variable path to my FileOutputStream?

My code right now:

```
System.out.print("Please insert name");
String fileName = scan.nextline();
path = System.getProperty("user.home") + "\\Desktop";
FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(path + fileName + ".xlsx");
```

But this doesn't work.
Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the end of your line `path = System.getProperty("user.home") + "\\Desktop";` (or in the line `FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(path + fileName + ".xlsx");` between the `path` variable and the `fileName` variable) you should add a `\` because your file will be called `C:\Users\You\Desktopaaaaaa.xlsx` instead of `C:\Users\You\Desktop\aaaaaa.xlsx` (see the missing backslash ?) and won't be at the desired location...

Comment: Or better yet, use `Paths.get(...)` instead of just concatenating Strings.

Comment: Yes you're absolutely right, but it will depend of which version of the JDK he uses because if I'm not making a mistake, Paths.get is available since Java 7.